# Hex value not represented as expected in C#

Tags: c#, wireshark, hex

I parce a pcap file which I have captured with tcpdump with SharpPcap. I have the code below:

```
 byte[] arr = new byte[] { 55, 53, 55, 53 };

 string hex = BitConverter.ToString(arr).Replace("-",String.Empty);
 //prints the hexvalue 37353735
```

In wireshark this hex value is represented in the correct 7575 (I know this is correct because this is the port I am sending too). However in Visual Studio I have not found out how to translate this hex value to the correct 7575. Using

```
int decAgain = int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

or using

`EndianBitConverter.Big.ToInt16(arr,0);`

does not seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: `37353735` is the correct hexadecimal representation of these bytes. `0x75` is equivalent to 117 in decimal.

Comment: I am a little confused. 55 decimal is 37 hex, not 75. And 53 is 35 hex.

Comment: Yes the hexvalue is 37 and 35. My problem is that in wireshark this hex value 37353735 is translated to 7575 but in my code I cannot get the correct 7575 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s = Encoding.Default.GetString(arr).Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

Edit: You tried to parse the bytes to hexadecimals, but they actually represent characters (have a look at an ASCII table e.g.).

Comment: Yes! that did it. However can you please add a small explanation to it so as understand it?

Comment: Note that `Encoding.Default` is installation dependent. It depends on your locale. You probably want `Encoding.ASCII` if it's ASCII text.